# Regex inconsistent

Tags: regex, perl

Using Resultset from my DB....

```
my $item_name = "Special Anniversary set by Brand Name"
my $item_name1 = $item_name;
$item_name1 =~ m/brand name/i;
$brand = $&; # a system var of the regex result
```

Brand outputs correctly:  'Brand Name'

```
my $item_name2 = $item_name;
$item_name2 =~ m/Special Anniversary by brand_name/i;
$sub_brand = $&; # a system var of the regex result
```

Sub brand outputs wrongly/inconsistently.

```
if ( $item_name eq 'Special Anniversary set by Brand Name' )
{
$brand outputs as 'Brand Name'; # correct
$sub_brand outputs as 'Special anniversary by Brand Name'; #correct
}
elsif( $item_name eq 'Something else by Brand Name' )
{
$brand outputs as 'Brand Name';# correct
$sub_brand = 'Brand Name'; #INCORRECT  I expect it to be null.

}
```

I hope that is sufficiently concise yet understandable.

However, in case not, the sub brand is returning the brand name (or perhaps the end of the desired string), if it doesn't match.

I guess it's returning the $& value from the first regex because it hasn't been overwritten with a match on the second regex.

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: There's a reason code examples of Perl regexes do 
 `if (/regex/) {
     # code that uses $1, $& etc...
 }` Good that you figured out what was going on ;)

Comment: Oh blimey/crikey; sounds like my pseudo code explanation was structured properly and better, than the real code I was using. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it's returning the `$&` value from the first regex because it hasn't been overwritten with a match on the second regex.

That is correct.

> I would appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Since you only want to use `$&` is the match was successful, check if the match was successful before using `$&`.

```perl
my $sub_brand;
if ($item_name2 =~ /Special Anniversary by brand_name/i) {
   $sub_brand = $&;
}
```

or

```perl
my $sub_brand = $item_name2 =~ /Special Anniversary by brand_name/i ? $& : undef;
```

You could also use

```perl
my ($sub_brand) = $item_name2 =~ /(Special Anniversary by brand_name)/i;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using the second option and will read up on the ? and : asap.

Comment: It's called the conditional operator. It's document in perlop. (Many erroneously call it the ternary operator. It is *a* ternary operator, but not *the* ternary operator.)

Comment: @ikegami, while you are technically right, I don't think there is another ternary operator in Perl, so even it is officially called the conditional operator, it is "the" ternary operator as far as perl is concerned. The documentation starts: `Ternary "?:" is the conditional operator, just as in C.` and uses "ternary" (as in "the") to refer to it in some places (e.g look at perdiag).

Comment: @Ecuador You literally just showed that the docs call it the conditional operator. That sentence just describes it as *a* ternary operator. And there's a good reason for that: Perl has many operators with ternary forms. `substr` is an operator with a ternary form (`substr(/a/, $_, -1)`), for example.

Comment: @ikegami, read my message more carefully. I said you are technically correct, because it is called the conditional operator. HOWEVER because it is Perl's ONLY ternary operator, the perldoc itself uses the name "the ternary operator" interchangeably (e.g.  `The question mark is also used as part of the ternary operator (as in foo ? 0 : 1 )`, `Mentioning the ternary operator in this error message...`. No, substr is not an operator, it is a function. It is "the ternary" operator, because it is the only one.

Comment: @Ecuador, You're the one who didn't read. I said it ISN'T Perl's only ternary operator, and I gave an example of another one. If you don't like the fact that the `substr` operator can also accept 1, 2 or 4 arguments, then there's `dbmopen`, `fcntl`, `getsockopt`, `ioctl`, `msgsnd`, `seek`, `semget`, `setpriority`, `shmctl`, `shmget`, `sysseek` and `vec` which always take exactly three operands.

Comment: @Ecuador, Re "*No, substr is not an operator, it is a function.*", It is an operator. Even the docs say so. Quote perlfunc: "*The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators.*" (There's also at least one nullary operator, `time`.) This can also be confirmed using `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'substr(/_/, $_, -1);'`. If it was a sub and not an operator, you'd see `entersub` instead of `substr`.

Comment: @Ecuador, Re "*the perldoc itself uses the name "the ternary operator" interchangeably*", That's no reason for you to make the same mistake, much less encourage others to make it.